# Single line in an SVG to polygons?

Tags: qgis, convert, line

I have a svg file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-u7dqmskzd5MEpuTmtZS3pDeHc

This is a single line that I want to convert into polygons.
If I understand correctly, I must convert it from svg to dxf first. Which I have done:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-u7dqmskzd5eHZURVVsU2FwQU0

What next? I tried many solutions and nothing works.

Comment: I use 2.18.4 version. I am beginner. I overreacted with "many solutions". Exactly I tried two ways, but I have no idea what to do next. 
1. I used algorithm "lines to polygons", but it changes output line. Line must be undisturbed. I don't know where are polygons created by algoritm. Does somebody know how to check it?
2. I instalIed 1.8 version to use "Polygonizer" plugin. It showed that it created 775 polygons, but it change output line too.

Comment: I've just used the Polygonize tool from the Processing toolbox and it doesn't work.

Comment: I want get polygon layer to color it like that: http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Qgis/Plugins/Documentation/topocolour/

Comment: Correction: Polygonize tool (Processing => QGIS geoalgorithmics => Vector geometry tools => Polygonize) works, but it changes the output line: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-u7dqmskzd5aV92ekI2QmNZOGc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the DXF.

Select the "shape" in the middle:

[image]

Run Polygonize.

Result:

[image]